# What is the ramification index of the extension field containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Suppose $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial over the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Let $\alpha, \beta$ be two roots of $f(x)$ with $p$-adic additive valuations $v(\alpha)=\frac{m}{p^2}$ and $v(\beta)=\frac{n}{p^2}$, for some natural numbers $m,n$.

What is the ramification index of the extension field containing both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ ?

How do we know whether two elements lies in the same extension field ?

Thanks

Comment: $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are Galois conjugates and therefore $m=n$, unless I’m mistaken.

Comment: @Mindlack, thanks. But I want to the ramification index of the extended field obtained by adjoining $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Is it $p^2/2$ ?

Comment: It obviously depends on a number of things – what about the $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial for instance?

Comment: Try with $\alpha= 1+p^{1/2}$. If $v(\alpha) = r/s,\gcd(r,s)=1$ (where $v(p)=1$) then we know that $s$ divides the ramification index of $K/\Bbb{Q}_p$ whenever $\alpha\in K$. We can't say much more than this, for example the ramification index of $\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/4},i2^{1/4})$ over $\Bbb{Q}_2$ is $8$, while that of $\Bbb{Q}_2(2^{1/4})$ and $\Bbb{Q}_2(i2^{1/4})$ is $4$.

Comment: @Mindlack, The $p$-th cyclotomic polynomial is $x^{p-1}+\cdots+x+1$. Then the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\zeta_p)$ has ramification index $\varphi(p)=p-1$. But I don't follow what do you mean in your comment ?

Comment: I meant that in this case the ramification index wasn’t $p^2$ (or $p$ or $p^2/2$) at all.

Comment: @Mindlack, ohh I see. Thanks. I have still one curiosity. Suppose $v(\alpha)=\frac{m}{p^2-1}$ and $v(\beta)=\frac{n}{p^2-1}$. When does $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lie in a field of with ramification index $\frac{p^2-1}{2}$ ? Can you please comment on such possibility or construct one such situation ?

Comment: If $p$ is odd and $m,n$ are even, then this is certainly possible (with $\mathbb{Q}_p(p^{1/(p^2-1)})$ for instance). But far from automatic: if you replace $\alpha$ with $\alpha+p^tu$, $\beta$ with $\beta+p^tv$ where $(\beta,v)$ is in the Galois orbit of $(\alpha,u)$ with $u$ integral such that $\mathbb{Q}_p(u)$ has a huge ramification index and contains $\alpha,\beta$ and $t$ large, then we don’t change the valuation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ but the underlying field grows arbitrarily large.

Comment: @Mindlack, thanks for your help